# What does "Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session" mean?

Tags: login, pam, debugging

Instead of logging me in, `PAM` greets me with the message "**Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session**" after I enter the password. What entry is it talking about (and what session)?

The string with the error message is found in `libpam.so.0`(.83.1).

My system is based on binaries from Fedora release 20 (Heisenburg).

How can I troubleshoot PAM to figure out what is needed to successfully login?
I have no syslog (and no persistent disk, only an initramfs).

### Updates:

SELinux is Disabled.

I am more than willing to replace the entire PAM config with something simple that allows login (normal user and root) on the virtual consoles only.

Source code from Linux-PAM-1.1.8, `libpam/pam_strerror.c` reveals that the message comes from the error code `PAM_SESSION_ERR`, which can be caused by all sorts of internal problems, such as memory allocation error or failure to locate the users home directory. So much for trying to interpret the error message. :-(

---

Below are my config files based on the comment indicating `/etc/pam.d/login` as a starting point:

(I have also tried removing all lines containing `pam_loginuid.so` without any noticeable difference)

---

**/etc/pam.d/login**:

```
auth [user_unknown=ignore success=ok ignore=ignore default=bad] pam_securetty.so
auth       substack     system-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      system-auth
password   include      system-auth
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_console.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so open
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      system-auth
session    include      postlogin
-session   optional     pam_ck_connector.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/postlogin**:

```
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service !~ gdm* service !~ su* quiet
session     [default=1]   pam_lastlog.so nowtmp showfailed
session     optional      pam_lastlog.so silent noupdate showfailed
```

**/etc/pam.d/system-auth**:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

---

**I have these shared PAM-related libraries**:

```
libpam_misc.so.0
libpam.so.0
pam_access.so
pam_console.so
pam_deny.so
pam_env.so
pam_fprintd.so
pam_gnome_keyring.so
pam_keyinit.so
pam_lastlog.so
pam_limits.so
pam_localuser.so
pam_loginuid.so
pam_namespace.so
pam_nologin.so
pam_permit.so
pam_pkcs11.so
pam_pwquality.so
pam_rootok.so
pam_securetty.so
pam_selinux_permit.so
pam_selinux.so
pam_sepermit.so
pam_succeed_if.so
pam_systemd.so
pam_timestamp.so
pam_unix_acct.so
pam_unix_auth.so
pam_unix.so
pam_xauth.so
```

**as well as these that are referenced by the above shared libraries (according to `ldd`)**:

```
libattr.so.1
libaudit.so.1
libcap.so.2
libcrack.so.2
libcrypt.so.1
libc.so.6
libdbus-1.so.3
libdbus-glib-1.so.2
libdl.so.2
libffi.so.6
libfreebl3.so
libgcc_s.so.1
libgio-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgmodule-2.0.so.0
libgobject-2.0.so.0
liblzma.so.5
libnsl.so.1
libnspr4.so
libnss3.so
libnssutil3.so
libpcre.so.1
libpcre.so.3
libplc4.so
libplds4.so
libpthread.so.0
libpwquality.so.1
libresolv.so.2
librt.so.1
libselinux.so.1
libsmime3.so
libssl3.so
libutil.so.1
libz.so.1
```

Comment: if you can't login as root you probably are in trouble. Where did you get the files in `/etc/pam.d` from?

Comment: @MattBianco seems similar to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/259867) reported a, long, while back. From the link, you should be able to use recovery disk and login as root. Once that's done, would you mind posting the content of `/etc/pam.d/login`? I can post mine, but it'll be better formatted in an answer box rather then comment; either way you prefer though.

Comment: The session it is talking about is the login session. The entry is some data it is trying to write to disk (or tmpfs) to help it keep track of this session. Look like the volume is mounted readonly, another permissions error, or missing directory, etc.

Comment: do you found solution?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I'm on Centos 6, and found this in /var/log/secure:

```
Mar 13 10:13:02 server sudo(pam_google_authenticator)[24911]: Unrecognized option "user=root"
Mar 13 10:13:02 server sudo:    ralph : pam_authenticate: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session ; TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/ralph ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/bin/become root
```

Ultimately, it was the GA PAM module barfing which PAM then doesn't know what to do with, so errors out. I'm sure numerous other problems with different PAM modules can cause the same behaviour (not just Google Authenticator). Some sort of log is probably the only way to find out what's going on though.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means an issue with a pam.d file - or with something that needs to be accessed by pam.

One debugging technique is to sprinkle pam_echo statements throughout your pam files:

e.g.

```
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "sshd: calling faillock" 
auth       requisite    pam_faillock.so preauth even_deny_root
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "sshd: faillock did not fail"
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "calling password-auth substack"
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "back from password-auth substack"
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "calling postlogin"
auth       include      postlogin
auth       [default=ignore] pam_echo.so "back from postlogin"
```

Be careful when adding pam_echo - do not to put it after lines that can 'skip' following lines, or if you must, update the number of lines to be skipped.

Reminder: always stay logged in as root while making changes to pam files - changes take effect immediately, and any mistake can leave you unable to login or sudo...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue on my own system by using the tool *audit2allow*. Check [my post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523365/sshd5589-error-pam-pam-open-session-cannot-make-remove-an-entry-for-the/523367#523367).