# Cronjobs not running. Cron daemon not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, logs, daemon

First of all, the server specs:

VPS - OpenVZ,
Ubuntu 14,
Kernel 3.10

Now, it appears that the cron daemon is not running ANY crojobs at all and i cannot find out why.

I tried:

- Rebooting the server.
- Restarting the `cron` daemon
- Changing permissions in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.daily` and `/var/spool/cron`
- Disabling one by one, the `cron` jobs from `crontab`, `cron.d` and spool ones.
- Changing permission in `/usr/sbin`
- Upgrading vixie cron
- Removing  the `pam_loginuid.so` in `pam.d`
- Changing passwords around (to the ones I think were the first ones)
- Tried making a `cron` job that outputs a logfile every minute in `/etc/crontab` file, user `crontab` and root `crontab`

and I still cannot find a solution.

*NOTE: Whenever i changed permissions to files, I used another fresh Debian install for reference.*

Also, there is this message that is being written to `cron.log` every minute and also, cannot find the source of it. Attaching image: [image: cron.log]

This is my last resort before doing a full system reinstall.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323754/cannot-make-remove-an-entry-for-the-specified-session-cron ? Specifically the workaround in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, but i already listed that as something i tried already to no avail

Comment: Since Ubuntu 14 is end-of-life, is upgrading to 16.04 or 18.04 an option?

Comment: The server is old but heavy in traffic so, i'm kinda afraid of making the upgrade without breaking everything up. But if there is no other option left, guess i'll have to do it anyways.

Comment: Related questions are  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152098/5132  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523365/5132 .

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment as yet so I have to post this as an answer.

You didn't mentioned whether you checked your /var/log/auth.log file.

This error is usually caused by a pam module so this log should give you some hints.

Comment: The last 2k lines of that file are just failed SSH login attempts from random people trying to brute force and nothing else